# Split an html file into multiple files in ionic2

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there any way to split a large html file into several files in ionic2?

I tried

```
<div ng-include src="file1.html"></div>
```

and

```
<link rel="import" href="./file1.html">
```

with no success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 dynamic template or ng-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328215/angular2-dynamic-template-or-ng-include)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div ng-include="'file1.htm'"></div>
```