# How to use ng-include with Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-include

I tried to include a html component in an other but I don't know how to resolve it by using ngInclude in angular 2/4...

my html component

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div ng-include="'folder_consult.html'"></div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried this code, but it does not work ..
Issue for using ngInclude ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 dynamic template or ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328215/angular2-dynamic-template-or-ng-include)

Comment: Thxx sooo muchh