# Passing Components in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Lets say i wanna get very abstract and modular and i want to pass components as input to my child components.

Is that possible?

I understand that i can pass the inputs and create the component internally, but sometimes i want to pass different/components otherwise i would have to customize the code to each component and i can't be abstract about the operation.

For Example, lets say i have component P as a parent and C as a child, i have a certain purpose for C such design and i would like to have C as a reusable component for whenever i want to implement this certain design with elements inside.

Now if i want to have C (two separate elements) wrap around two different components let's call them A & B. i want P to be able to pass them after creating them to C to keep the design abstract while being able to just use the components as a variable inside C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Actually is how composition for modular components works in Angular2.

So for example if you have a modal component and you want to use that all over the app, but that component is just a wrapper and it is needed to add dynamic components to it.

Here it's an example with the  **ComponentFactoryResolver** :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dynamic-component',
  template: 'this is a dynamic injected component !'
})
export class MyDynamicComponent {}


@Component({ 
  selector: 'wrapper',
  template: `
  <div>
    <p>Wrapper Component</p>
    <template #dynamicComponent></template> 
  </div>
  `
})
export class WrapperComponent {
  @Input() contentComponent: any;
  @ViewChild('dynamicComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef })

  dynamicComponent: any;

  constructor(private componentResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngAfterViewInit():void {
    const factory = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.contentComponent);

    this.dynamicComponent.createComponent(factory);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ` 
  <wrapper [contentComponent]="MyDynamicComponent"></wrapper>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    MyDynamicComponent: any = MyDynamicComponent;
}
```

Inspired from [deprecated ComponentResolver answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093727/angular2-insert-a-dynamic-component-as-child-of-a-container-in-the-dom/38095442#comment65757016_38095442) 
Another way of doing this can be found [answer HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-component-with-angular2-rc6/38888009#comment65766471_38888009)

[Example PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/g66jiuV14Tph8XylhRFV?p=preview)

Comment: In rc5-6 use ComponentFactoryResolve resolver to get factory

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!