# Loading different templates in a component based on condition in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Scenario:

I have a component say, COMP which has to load either of the two templates, say, TEMPLATE_1 or TEMPLATE_2 based on the type of user logged in (Say, ADMIN user and NORMAL user).

How to do it using Angular 2 latest release?

Disclaimer: I am new to Angular 2.

Comment: I don't know why is this question marked negative. If you know the answer please share it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic template URLs in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692416/dynamic-template-urls-in-angular-2)

Comment: Also you may want to take a look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381855/passing-components-in-angular2/39382636#39382636

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using:

- Structural directive `ngIf` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

or

- Dynamic component loading http://blog.lacolaco.net/post/dynamic-component-creation-in-angular-2-rc-5/

P.S. You get downvote because your question is too broad and you haven't shown what you've tried so far.