# convert text to html format in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am creating post request with promise, using angular 6. In my service I created 
a request function which looks like this:

```
sendRequest() {
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  this.http.post(this.url, this.params, {responseType: 'text'}).toPromise()
  .then(res =>{
    this.data = res;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('1/success'); // I want to show res code on this page
    resolve();
  },
  error => {
    this.data = error;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('1/fail');
    reject(error);
  } 
)
return promise;
})}
```

res returns text in html format like that:

`<html>
  <head>
    some code
  </head>
  <body>
    code i need
  </body>
</html>`
, which is fine, but I would like to use that text as html code on success/fail page. Specifically, everything that is in body tag. How can i achieve that? If i use anything like

```
<div [innerHTML]="res"></div>
```

or

```
{{res}}
```

it just returns plain text.

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339039/angular-5-add-dynamic-html-file-into-div/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular **encodes** the values returned by the api for security purposes. 
You have to use the **DomSanitizer** service in your service to bypass it.

First inject the service:

```
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
```

Then use it in your **sendRequest** function:

```
this.data = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res);
```

And then in your html file:

```
<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>
```

**Note:**

Trusting values in HTML format may pose a **security risk** as mentioned in the [docs](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#security-risk).

Comment: It doesn't work. For some reason it cuts out whole string so it results in blank page.

Comment: How are you transferring the res value to the success/fail component?

Comment: as it says code above, in service where i make a request: this.data = res;
then in suc/fail comp. i have
data:string = this.myService.data;

Answer (score 3):

Using `innerHTML` like this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="res"></div>
```

Make sure you got controller somewhere around that, maybe you forgot it?

It should work according to this:
[Angular - template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

Comment: already did that, but it results in random snipped of the whole which doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

```
<div [innerHtml]="challenges_Data.challenges"></div>
```

here challenges_Data is an object and challenges is the values of challenges_Data .