# Loading html template with ngModel from the server response

Tags: angular, innerhtml, dynamic-html

Using angular v10.

In server response,

```
body.data = '<p> My name is <input type"text" [(ngModel)]="nameModel">. </p>';
```

But **innerHTML** won't process ngModel or any other click events. **Went through many stack overflow links but couldn't find an appropriate answer to my query**. Can someone help  me here?

Comment: Try this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339039/angular-5-add-dynamic-html-file-into-div/

Comment: @PranjalSuccessena this won't work for me