# How to append HTML tags or elements to a div in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I have a div in a template that has #divMessages as a template reference name.

```
<div  #divMessages></div>
```

When some events occur, I want to append HTML tags to this div. I tried in the following way but HTML tags appended as a string.

```
this.divMessages.nativeElement.append('<li>'+data.message+ '</li>');
```

My current method considers HTML tags as a string.
How I can append HTML tags, to hide the tags and show only the data. (means only list items are shown and the tags are hidden in the above case).

Comment: Possibly similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682801/angular2-add-html-to-dynamic-elements

Comment: thanks man, it seems i did't crawl the stackoverflow completely.

Comment: Just use an ngFor in your div, iterating over an array pf data, and add data to the array. If you're doing DOM manipulation i Angular, you're doing it wrong. You modify the model, and the view is updated automatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the Renderer2 Abstract class, Which is a service provided by Angular to Manipulate DOM elements.
Import the Renderer2 from angular core. then create element and append text to it.

```
  import {Component, OnInit,NgModule, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

pass Renderer2  object to class constructur.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient,private renderer:Renderer2) { }

//create the DOM element 
let li=this.renderer.createElement('li');

//create text for the element
const text = this.renderer.createText(data.message);

//append text to li element
  this.renderer.appendChild(li, text);

//Now append the li tag to divMessages div
this.renderer.appendChild(this.divMessages.nativeElement,li);
```

i used @ViewChild decorator to get the div as a divMessages

```
 @ViewChild("divMessages", {read: ElementRef}) private divMessages: ElementRef;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div [innerHTML]="divMessages"></div>
```

in typescript you can append by this way

```
var appendElement = '<li>'+data.message+'</li>' ;
this.divMessages = appendElement;
```