# Angular: How detect image direction afterview or when i get the images from database?

Tags: javascript, angular, image, typescript

I am trying to do a thumbail of images that centered and cropped, so i get from database. I have found this information about how to do it:
https://aaronparecki.com/2016/08/13/4/css-thumbnails

That resource is written for javascript and i am using Angular 7. So, I am having problems to detect if an image is portrait or not.

I have tried to add the class portrait when i get all the photos before load in page, but the problem is that is a path what i get from DataBase, so I built and Image object. The code is that:

```
 getPhotosUser(page) {
    this._photoService.getPhotosUser(this.user.id, page).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.photos = response.objects

     var addImageOrientationClass = function (img) {
      var imgObject = new Image();
      imgObject.src = img;
      if(imgObject.naturalHeight > imgObject.naturalWidth){
        img.classList.add("portrait")
      }
    }

    this.photos.forEach(function (value: any) {
      console.log("PHTOOOSOASAOSIA")
      value.path = environment.api.replace('/api', '/') + value.path.replace('app/', '');
      addImageOrientationClass(value.path)
    })
  }
)
}
```

The error that i get is that one:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

I have also try to put it or something similar in afterview, but I dont get values for images (as example in the resource above). In resume, my code is like:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     var addImageOrientationClass = function (img) {
       console.log(typeof(img))
       if (img.naturalHeight > img.naturalWidth) {
         img.classList.add("portrait")
       }
     }
     var images = document.querySelectorAll("thumbnail img");
     images.forEach(function (value: any){
       if (value.complete){
         addImageOrientationClass(value)
       }else{
         value.addEventListener("load", function(evt){
          addImageOrientationClass(evt.target)
         })
       }
     })
  }
```

Images is empty and for that, i dont get any image if someone can help me or told me about a library useful for doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason why you are getting "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" is your "img.classList" is undefined, since your are passing  img="environment.api.replace('/api', '/') + value.path.replace('app/', '');"  which is a mere string, as per your code you need to pass an object

Comment: But, how can I fix it? Because in html I use a for with the strings, not with the objects

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize your problem, so your requirement is to load images from database and render them as thumbnails, centered and cropped.

So basic idea for the implementation is :

a) Thumbnail : Just wrap image tag inside anchor tag this will be rendered as thumbnail

b) Centered and cropped : Use the same css, the document you are referring.

c) To Load images Dynamically :

```
 1) Create placeholders for anchor->image tag  nested inside your photos array
 2) map image source dynamically : <img [src]="urlVariable" />
```

PS: The javascript code what you referred is just for the orientation, if you want to create Image elements dynamically and render those in Angular, you can refer:

[Angular-renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341497/how-to-append-html-tags-or-elements-to-a-div-in-angular-6?answertab=votes#tab-top)