# Angular2 - Component into dynamically created element

Tags: google-maps, angular

I use google maps javascript api and I have to display an Angular component into the InfoWindow.

In my project I load the google map api with the `Jsonp` service. Than I have the `google.maps.Map` object available. Later in a component I create some markers and attach to them a click listener :

**TypeScript** :

```
let marker = new google.maps.Marker(opts);
marker.setValues({placeId: item[0]});
marker.addListener('click', (ev: google.maps.MouseEvent) => this.onMarkerClick(marker, ev));
```

And then in the `click` handler I want to open an Info Window that contains an Angular Component:

**TypeScript** :

```
private onMarkerClick(marker: google.maps.Marker, ev: google.maps.MouseEvent) {

    var div = document.createElement();
    this.placeInfoWindow.setContent(div);
    // Magic should happen here somehow
    // this.placeInfoWindow.setContent('<app-info-view-element></app-info-view-element>');
    this.placeInfoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
}
```

What I ended up doing was some vanilla JS:

**TypeScript** :

```
 private onMarkerClick(marker: google.maps.Marker, ev: google.maps.MouseEvent) {


    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'map-info-window-container';
    div.style.height = '140px';
    div.style.width = '240px';

    this.placeInfoWindow.setContent(div);

    this.placeInfoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    this.placesService.getPlace(marker.get('id')).subscribe(res => {
      this.decorateInfoWindow(div, res.name, marker);
    }, error => {
      this.decorateInfoWindow(div, ':( Failed to load details: ', marker);
    });

  }



private decorateInfoWindow(containerEl: HTMLElement, title?:string, marker?:google.maps.Marker) {
    let h3 = document.createElement('h3');
    h3.innerText = title;
    containerEl.appendChild(h3);

    let buttonBar = document.createElement('div');
    let editButton = document.createElement('button')
    editButton.innerText = "Edit";
    editButton.addEventListener('click', ev => {
      this.editPlace(marker);
    });
    buttonBar.appendChild(editButton);
    containerEl.appendChild(buttonBar);
  }
```

---

The problem, as I learned, Is that the only viable way to create dynamic components is to use Angulars `ViewContainerRef`:

- [How to place a dynamic component in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185820/how-to-place-a-dynamic-component-in-a-container)

But there are no docs or examples, describing how to create a `ViewContainerRef` from a dynamically created element.

---

Is it posible to force the framework to process the DOM in some way ?  As it is in a lot of threads is stated : "Angular does not process `innerHTML` or `appendChild`". Is this a complete dead end ?

Second: Is it possible using a `Renderer` implementation ? (Not Familiar with it), I saw this [Canvas Renderer Experiment](https://github.com/matsko/angular2-canvas-renderer-experiment) and theoretically, I guess it would work also with the Google map, since we can extrapolate that the map is just a special kind of canvas. Is it still available in the last release or it changed ? `DomRenderer` is not in the docs, however one can find it in the sources.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main rule here is **to create component dynamically you need to get its factory.**

1) Add dynamic component to `entryComponents` array besides including into `declarations`:

```typescript
@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [ 
    AppInfoWindowComponent,
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    AppInfoWindowComponent,
    ...
  ],
})
```

That is a hint for angular compiler to produce ngfactory for the component even if we don't use our component directly within some of template.

2) Now we need to inject `ComponentFactoryResolver` to our component/service where we want to get ngfactory. You can think about `ComponentFactoryResolver` like a storage of component factories

**app.component.ts**

```typescript
import { ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core'
...
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}
```

3) It's time to get `AppInfoWindowComponent` factory:

```typescript
const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AppInfoWindowComponent);
this.compRef = compFactory.create(this.injector);
```

4) Having factory we can freely use it how we want. Here are some cases:

- `ViewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory,...)` inserts component next to viewContainer.
- `ComponentFactory.create(injector, projectableNodes?, rootSelectorOrNode?)` just creates component and this component can be inserted into element that matches `rootSelectorOrNode`

Note that we can provide node or selector in the third parameter of `ComponentFactory.create` function. It can be helpful in many cases. In this example i will simply create component and then insert into some element.

`onMarkerClick` method might look like:

```typescript
onMarkerClick(marker, e) {
  if(this.compRef) this.compRef.destroy();

  // creation component, AppInfoWindowComponent should be declared in entryComponents
  const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(AppInfoWindowComponent);
  this.compRef = compFactory.create(this.injector);

  // example of parent-child communication
  this.compRef.instance.param = "test";
  const subscription = this.compRef.instance.onCounterIncremented.subscribe(x => { this.counter = x; });  

  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);

  this.placeInfoWindow.setContent(div);
  this.placeInfoWindow.open(this.map, marker);

  // 5) it's necessary for change detection within AppInfoWindowComponent
  // tips: consider ngDoCheck for better performance
  this.appRef.attachView(this.compRef.hostView);
  this.compRef.onDestroy(() => {
    this.appRef.detachView(this.compRef.hostView);
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

5) Unfortunatelly dynamically created component is not part of change detection tree therefore we also need to take care about change detection. It can be done by using `ApplicationRef.attachView(compRef.hostView)` as has been written in example above or we can do it explicity with `ngDoCheck`([example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1C7RtTxAZVTYpEmbKjV9?p=preview)) of component where we're creating dynamic component(`AppComponent` in my case)

**app.component.ts**

```typescript
ngDoCheck() {
  if(this.compRef) {
    this.compRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
  }
}
```

This approach is better because it will only update dynamic component if current component is updated. On the other hand `ApplicationRef.attachView(compRef.hostView)` adds change detector to the root of change detector tree and therefore it will be called on every change detection tick.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/zyzs6LtVpQKeiz9JryJ9?p=preview)**

---

*Tips:*

Because `addListener` is running outside angular2 zone we need to explicity run our code inside angular2 zone:

```typescript
marker.addListener('click', (e) => { 
  this.zone.run(() => this.onMarkerClick(marker, e));
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: @Jigar Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: @yurzui; Sorry for the comment, change detection is working too.

Comment: @MichalMoravcik Yes, it does

Comment: @yurzui, thanks a lot, I will definitively give it a try, looks promising

Comment: @yurzui, according to description on [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html#!#attachView-anchor) for `attachView`, it says and I quote ''The view will be automatically detached when it is destroyed'' ... so I conclude that subscribing on `onDestroy` to detach the view is obsolete?

Comment: @yurzui: Thank you so much. Solved my issue as well.