# Angular 2 stand alone components

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, frontend

Just moved over to Angular 2 recently and i am just trying to get my head around pretty much all of it.

I need to build and that just uses stand-alone components, I want to be able to utilise my components as follows.

```
<body>
   <component-one></component-one>
   <component-two></component-two>
</body>
```

I have got as far as getting these components to render out on the page the problem is when one of these component selectors are not present on the current page i get the following console error...

```
core.umd.js:2838 EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "component-one" did not match any elements
```

Is there a way to only bootstrap only the relevant components?

Also, the "Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode." console message comes in multiples times depending on how many components i have on the page, which makes me feel like i am missing something.

Module config

```
// Modules
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Components
import { ComponentOne }  from './components/componentOne';
import { ComponentTwo }  from './components/componentTwo';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ ComponentOne, ComponentTwo ],
  bootstrap:    [ ComponentOne, ComponentTwo],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { 
   constructor() {

}
```

}

Comment: Can you add your module configuration?

Comment: Sure @yurzui it's updated now.

Answer (score 3):

You can omit the bootstrap option and implementing `ngDoBootstrap()` yourself.
And to conditionally bootstrap components, just do a `querySelector` before calling `appRef.bootstrap(SomeComponent);` to check whether the component is already on the page.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ ComponentOne, ComponentTwo ],
  entryComponents: [ ComponentOne, ComponentTwo ]
})
export class AppModule { 
  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    if(document.querySelector('component-one')) {
      appRef.bootstrap(ComponentOne);
    }
    if(document.querySelector('component-two')) {
      appRef.bootstrap(ComponentTwo);
    }
  }
}
```

*Note:* `entryComponents` option is required

Finally in your index.html you can omit second tag and angular won't raise error:

```
<body>
  <component-one></component-one>
</body>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZcPVRUF1tVz99OakFJgg?p=preview)**

If you don't want to see message `Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.` you can just enable prod mode or use the following (Since 2.3.0) which is similar as above (**i recommend to use the first solution**):

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ ComponentOne, ComponentTwo ],
  entryComponents: [ComponentOne, ComponentTwo]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private inj: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {   
    if(document.querySelector('component-one')) {
      const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ComponentOne);
      let compOneRef = compFactory.create(this.inj, [], 'component-one');
      appRef.attachView(compOneRef.hostView);
      compOneRef.onDestroy(() => {
        appRef.detachView(compOneRef.hostView);
      });
    }
    if(document.querySelector('component-two')) {
      const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ComponentTwo);
      let compTwoRef = compFactory.create(this.inj, [], 'component-one');
      appRef.attachView(compTwoRef.hostView);
      compTwoRef.onDestroy(() => {
        appRef.detachView(compTwoRef.hostView);
      });
    }

    appRef.tick();
  }
}
```

It's just the same that angular does internally when bootstraping component

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/yxDhQOz0F7086Ehb3EhP?p=preview)**

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11730
- [Angular2 - Component into dynamicaly created element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922224/angular2-component-into-dynamicaly-created-element)

Comment: But wouldn't i still be getting "Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode."  for each component that gets bootstrapped ?

Comment: It's just debugging information. It's calling for each bootstrap component https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.3.0/modules/%40angular/core/src/application_ref.ts#L449-L475. After enabling prod mode it will go away

Comment: So it's not running a new instance of angular core for each component ?

Comment: No, it's just bootstraping component and attaching it to change detection. It's recommended angular2 team way. See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11730

Comment: Do you think there could be a good way to write a module that pretty much handles it rather then having it in the ngDoBootstrap?

Comment: is there a way i can loop through components and there properties from a module?