# Angular 2 Pipes with string evaluation

Tags: angular, components, string-evaluation

Inside component.ts:

```
var bannerContent = `<div>
    Created = ${item.created_at | date}
</div>`;
```

Throws error on console: 'date is not defined.'

Following is also not working and prints as this as it is (without evaluating)

```
var bannerContent = `<div>
    Created = {{item.created_at | date}}
</div>`;
```

**Update:**
Usage of this variable is like:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: bannerContent});
  ...
  ...
});
```

Comment: how you adding `bannerContent` in your template?

Comment: this bannerContent is for google maps marker. I pass this to google maps InfoWindow

Comment: The question doesn't make sense without the context. Please, provide the code for how exactly `bannerContent` is used. If you just pass the variable to third-party API, it will obviously won't work. It should be bound in view with `[innerHTML]=...` in order to take effect.

Comment: @estus Your comment make sense. But API ref of date pipe says this returns a string, and that should work: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html

Comment: It should't work because bannerContent contents aren't parsed by Angular compiler. If `item.created_at` doesn't have to be bound, you can try to apply a pipe manually to its value, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144821/angular-2-use-pipes-in-services

Comment: Check also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922224/angular2-component-into-dynamicaly-created-element