# *ngIf in google maps InfoWindow in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps-api-3

How Can i use `*ngIf` inside google Maps `InfoWindow` so that i can hide or show a `Div` based on a button i click in `InfoWindow`?

This is my Current Code:

```js
let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: '<div id="iw-container" *ngIf="showList">'+
  '<div class="alert-box">Regd: ' +Data[i].foo.registration+'</div>'+
  '<div class="alert-box" *ngIf="showList">Phone: ' +Data[i].foo.id.phoneNumbers[0]+'</div>'+
  '<div *ngIf="showList">Hi</div>'+
  '<button class=List">View List</button>'+
  '</div>'
});
self.marker[reg].infowindow = infowindow;
```

function to change the flag which i've declared after the above line:

```
$('.List').click(function(){
  self.showList = !self.showList;
  self.showDataList(i);
});
```

`showDataList()` will give some data which i want to handle later.

`*ngIf` works only once and later it just fails.

I have multiple markers which i'm storing in `marker[]`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: My guess is that you should use `$compile` for this..

Comment: Also, how `showList` is a function **and88 `boolean` variable?!

Comment: @Mosh Feu my bad , forgot to copy it properly. Have Made the hanges

Comment: Something like `$compile` won't work with aot

Comment: Check also this answer as possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922224/angular2-component-into-dynamicaly-created-element/40926110#40926110