# Angular 2 / leaflet map, How to link to a component from marker popup ? ... routerLink?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, angular2-routing, typescript2.0

Inside my angular 2 app I have a leaflet map with a popup bound to a onClick event.

The content of the popup has a link to an angular component. however when I use routerLink inside the .setContent() function the link doesn't show.

I'm guessing this is happening because .setContent() is not able to render angular 2 directives which makes sense. what can I use instead?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  openmap: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let openmap = L.tileLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}", {
      attribution: 'terms and feedback'
    });

    let map = L.map("map", {
      center: [33.2148, -97.1331],
      zoom: 5,
      zoomControl: true,
      maxZoom: 18 
    }).addLayer(openmap);

    let marker = L.marker([39.2148, -98.1331]).addTo(map);

    let popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
      popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("Facility" + "<br/>" + "<a routerLink='/view2'>" + "View Two" + "</a>")
        .openOn(map);
    }

    map.on('click', onMapClick);
  }

}
```

Needles, to say if I change it to

```
 .setContent("Facility" + "<br/>" + "<a href='../view2'>" + "View Two" + "</a>")
```

Will do what I want, but this will cause a page refresh, so this is not an option.

Comment: No one has a solution to this?

Comment: Doesnt look like it...I still need it, my map link is slow :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a very simple approach and a very complex one.

The simple approach is to use raw HTML with anchor element outside of angular without **RouterLink**. Register to clicks on that anchor element and use the **Router** service to navigate.

The task was to fire links but the actual problem is far deeper, now it links next time its showing an angular component...

So, for the complex solution:

This is an highly advanced topic... Not only it involves using advanced angular techniques it's also advanced in the leaflet implementation.

I'll do my best to convey the message but due to the complexity the examples will be very simple and will require work.

### First - Angular realm.

An HTML string that contains directives, components or pipes will never work, the only way is to initialize a **View**

Let's define A **View** as a reference to view instance of a **component** or a **template**.

These are called **ComponentRef** and **TemplateRef**

So, we have 2 ways to solve this problem. Since I can't do both i'll go with **ComponentRef** but note that you can also use **TemplateRef**.
With templates you'll first need to obtain a template defined in the component as well as a **ViewContainerRef** to attach that template to.

We will build a service that accepts a leaflet **Marker** and binds to the click event of the marker, on click it will open a popup which is an angular Component.

The component is simple, it renders a link.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'facility-link',
  template: `Facility <br/> <a routerLink="{{link}}"> View Two</a>`
})
export class FacilityLinkComponent {
  public link: string;
  constructor() { }
}
```

Now, for the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LinkPopupService {

  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private injector: Injector,
              private appRef: ApplicationRef) { }


  register(marker: leaflet.Marker, link: string): void  {
    marker.on('click', ($event: leaflet.MouseEvent)  => this.popup($event.target, link) );
  }

  popup(marker: leaflet.Marker, link: string) {
    const cmpFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(FacilityLinkComponent);
    const componentRef = cmpFactory.create(this.injector);
    componentRef.instance.link = link;
    this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
    const markerElement = marker.getElement();
    markerElement.parentElement.appendChild(componentRef.location.nativeElement);

    const markerPos = leaflet.DomUtil.getPosition(markerElement);
    const markerClass = leaflet.DomUtil.getClass(markerElement);


    leaflet.DomUtil.setTransform(componentRef.location.nativeElement, markerPos);
    leaflet.DomUtil.setClass(componentRef.location.nativeElement, markerClass);
  }
}
```

The **register** method accepts a marker and the link and registers to the click event.

When the **popup** method fires it uses angular tools to create a view instance of **FacilityLinkComponent**, set the link for future binding, attach a view to it and attach it to the DOM.

This all happens in the first 5 lines of code.

Some notes:

- We must attach a view so change detection works
- A Proper implementation will allow to set **ViewContainerRef** and / or an **Injector** - this is a must when using lazy loading.
- It is preferred sending data to the component via Injector and not by assignment (ReflectiveInjector)
- Proper clean up is required (destroy the component and detach the view)
- Need to add toggle logic, also clean on navigation.

### Leaflet

The code from the 6th line performs positioning of the popup.

This is a very simple logic, it just copies everything from the marker.

This is why I used a marker, so I'll have a reference to take the positioning from.

In a realworld example you'll need to get a panel and push the components into their own layer, computing the position. This is not that difficult since leaflet has all the helper, but it was too much for this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me alot, the setup was a bit complex, but once done and you can reuse it for any future project which needs complex interactions on leaflet popups. A big thumbs up!

2 comments:

1. You dont need to detach the view, it will be automatically detached on component.destroy()

2: You have to intercept the standard map click event, leaflet triggers the map.on('click'...) if you click on the view, I achieved this with a hack (if the view got clicked => dont execute the usual mapclick code)

Comment: @JonasOstergaard Can you post your solution, perhaps through a working github/plunker example?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same requirement.
I just did it in a simple way.

As per your code you can add changes like this

```
private _popUpContent: string = '"Facility" + "<br/>" + "<a id="view_two">" + "View Two" + "</a>"';

constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer , public ngZone : NgZone,public elementRef : ElementRef){}

 function onMapClick(e) {
      popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent(safeLink) //throws type error
        .openOn(map);

        popup.on('popupopen' , () => {
          this.initInfoWindowEventListner();
        })
    }

function initInfoWindowEventListner(){
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector("#view_two")
    .addEventListener('click', (e : any)=> {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/view2])
      })
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the answer of @Vijay Kumar. I have multiple markers, and wanted the buttons' actions to be different based on the marker.

```
map.on('popupopen', (e) => {
    const _latlng = e.target._popup._latlng;
    const lat = _latlng.lat + 4;
    map.setView([lat, _latlng.lng], e.target._zoom);
    // Events listeners
    addDeviceControlEventListener(this.elementRef, this.ngZone, this.router);
    addDeviceAlarmsEventListener(this.elementRef, this.ngZone, this.dialogService);
});

addDeviceControlEventListener(elementRef: ElementRef, ngZone: NgZone, router: Router) {
    const list = elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a.device-control-btn');
    for (const item of list) {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e: any) => {
            ngZone.run(() => router.navigateByUrl(`pages/device/${item.getAttribute('imei')}`));
        });
    }
}

addDeviceAlarmsEventListener(elementRef: ElementRef, ngZone: NgZone, dialogService: NbDialogService) {
    const list = elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a.device-alarms-btn');
    for (const item of list) {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e: any) => {
            ngZone.run(() => dialogService.open(DeviceAlarmsComponent, {
                context: { deviceKey: item.getAttribute('imei') },
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

The buttons in `bindPopup` are as follows

```
<a imei="${device.key}" class="device-control-btn"> Device Operation</a>
<a imei="${device.key}" class="device-alarms-btn"> Device Alarms</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

**This answer does not work. I will leave it up for now in case someone has a solution. I think it shows the issue that Angular needs SafeHtml   for a routerLink (see [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) 
) and Leaflet will only pass a string to a popup using 
[.setContent()](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#popup-setcontent) or [.bindPopup()](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layer-bindpopup)

The code below is based on  [Sanitize input in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467000/sanitize-input-in-angular2)

```
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

  private _popUpContent: string = '"Facility" + "<br/>" + "<a routerLink='/view2'>" + "View Two" + "</a>"';

  private htmlProperty(): SafeHtml {
     return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._popUpContent);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let safeLink = this.htmlProperty();

    let openmap = L.tileLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}", {
      attribution: 'terms and feedback'
    });

    let map = L.map("map", {
      center: [33.2148, -97.1331],
      zoom: 5,
      zoomControl: true,
      maxZoom: 18 
    }).addLayer(openmap);

    let marker = L.marker([39.2148, -98.1331]).addTo(map);

    let popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
      popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent(safeLink) //throws type error
        .openOn(map);
    }

    map.on('click', onMapClick);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using bindPopup to set a popup on a marker, which requires the content to be a string, and is erroring on SafeHtml type.  My code is:

let marker = L.marker([location.latitude, location.longitude], {icon: blueIcon}).bindPopup(
  html
).addTo(this.map);

Comment: You are correct. My answer doesn't work. It's just as you describe -- .setContent() will accept a function but only if it returns a string. htmlProperty() returns type SafeHtml.

Comment: Sorry, my comment got cut off somehow.  I was asking if there was a good solution for bindPopup that allows dynamic injections of html containing routerLinks?