# Can't bind component in leaflet setContent function

Tags: angular, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I use a leaflet in my angular project and I need to open a custom modal on the map's pin click.
I find some code that works but I need to put my custom component instead of HTML code as you see below:

```
.setContent(`<a target="_blank" >test text</a>`)
```

how can I have something like this that include html,css,ts files:

```
.setContent(`<my-component></my-component>`)
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340067/angular-component-into-leaflet-popup).