# How to spawn Angular 4 component inside a Leaflet marker's popup?

Tags: angular, leaflet, web-component

I've been a long Angular 1.x user and now I'm working on make a new app using Angular 4. I still don't grasp most of the concepts but I finally have something working really nice. However, I'm having an issue where I need to display an Angular 4 component (although in 1.x I just used directives) inside a Marker's popup using Leaflet.

Now, in Angular 1.x I could just use $compile against a template with the directive inside it (`` `<component>{{ text }}</component>` ``) with buttons and such and it would work, but Angular 4 is totally different with its AoT thing and compiling at runtime seems to be really hard and there's no easy solution for it.

I asked a question [here](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/unfortunately-it-is-impossible-to-take-elements-that-are-added-dynamically-at-run-time-4f997fd6bb24) and the author says I could use a directive. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or even how to mix my own code with his proposed solution... so I made a small npm-based project with Angular 4 and Leaflet already set up in case you know how to help me or want to give it a try (I greatly appreciate it!). I've been banging my head around this for maybe a week and I'm really tired of trying a lot of alternatives without success :(

Here's the link of my repo in GitHub: https://github.com/darkguy2008/leaflet-angular4-issue

The idea is to spawn PopupComponent (or anything similar to it) inside a Marker, code which you can find in src/app/services/map.service.ts, line 38.

Thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT**

I managed to solve it :) see the marked answer for details, or this diff. There are a few caveats and the procedure for Angular 4 and Leaflet is a bit different and it doesn't require as much changes: https://github.com/darkguy2008/leaflet-angular4-issue/commit/b5e3881ffc9889645f2ae7e65f4eed4d4db6779b

I've also made a Custom Compile Service out of this solution explained [here](https://medium.com/@dark.guy.2008/compile-for-angular-4-ff800de4a77b) and uploaded to the same GitHub repo. Thanks @yurzui! :)

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922224/angular2-component-into-dynamicaly-created-element ?

Comment: Hello @ghybs, I did a few days ago but I didn't have much success. Guess what, I was trying to add the solution into a Service. It doesn't seem to work with Services but with Components instead. I have made a commit to the GitHub repo with the solution... but I don't think it'd be fair to answer my own question since you did provide a key link with information. Do you want to enter an answer so I can mark it as such, or shall I answer my own question? THANKS!

Comment: Well, way to go @yurzui, I could've answered my own question and at least get a few rep points and clarify stuff for next readers, now I can't aside from just editing the main question. Awesome. Leaflet != Google Maps, just for future reference...

Comment: @DARKGuy Sorry, just do it

Comment: Oh haha, I thought this change wasn't reversible, thanks @yurzui! Will do :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alright, so thanks to @ghybs's suggestion I gave that link another try and managed to solve the issue :D. Leaflet is a bit different from Google Maps (it's also shorter) and the proposed solution there could be a bit smaller and easier to understand, so here's my version using Leaflet.

Basically, you need to put your popup component in the main app module's `entryComponents` field. The key stuff is in `m.onclick()`, there, we create a component, render it inside a `div` and then we pass that `div`'s content to the leaflet popup container element. A bit tricky, but it works.

I got some time and converted this solution to a new $compile for Angular 4. Check the detailed info [here](https://medium.com/@dark.guy.2008/compile-for-angular-4-ff800de4a77b). Thanks @yurzui! :)

This is the core code... The other stuff (css, webpack, etc.) is in the same repo as the OP, simplified into few files: https://github.com/darkguy2008/leaflet-angular4-issue but you just need this example to make it work:

```
import 'leaflet';
import './main.scss';
import "reflect-metadata";
import "zone.js/dist/zone";
import "zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { Component, NgModule, ComponentRef, Injector, ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injectable, NgZone } from "@angular/core";

// ###########################################
// App component
// ###########################################
@Component({
    selector: "app",
    template: `<section class="app"><map></map></section>`
})
class AppComponent { }

// ###########################################
// Popup component
// ###########################################
@Component({
    selector: "popup",
    template: `<section class="popup">Popup Component! :D {{ param }}</section>`
})
class PopupComponent { }

// ###########################################
// Leaflet map service
// ###########################################
@Injectable()
class MapService {

    map: any;
    baseMaps: any;
    markersLayer: any;

    public injector: Injector;
    public appRef: ApplicationRef;
    public resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver;
    public compRef: any;
    public component: any;

    counter: number;

    init(selector) {
        this.baseMaps = {
            CartoDB: L.tileLayer("http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
            })
        };
        L.Icon.Default.imagePath = '.';
        L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
            iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
            shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png')
        });
        this.map = L.map(selector);
        this.baseMaps.CartoDB.addTo(this.map);
        this.map.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        this.markersLayer = new L.FeatureGroup(null);
        this.markersLayer.clearLayers();
        this.markersLayer.addTo(this.map);
    }

    addMarker() {
        var m = L.marker([51.510, -0.09]);
        m.bindTooltip('Angular 4 marker (PopupComponent)');
        m.bindPopup(null);
        m.on('click', (e) => {
            if (this.compRef) this.compRef.destroy();
            const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
            this.compRef = compFactory.create(this.injector);

            this.compRef.instance.param = 0;
            setInterval(() => this.compRef.instance.param++, 1000);

            this.appRef.attachView(this.compRef.hostView);
            this.compRef.onDestroy(() => {
                this.appRef.detachView(this.compRef.hostView);
            });
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);
            m.setPopupContent(div);
        });
        this.markersLayer.addLayer(m);
        return m;
    }
}

// ###########################################
// Map component. These imports must be made
// here, they can't be in a service as they
// seem to depend on being loaded inside a
// component.
// ###########################################
@Component({
    selector: "map",
    template: `<section class="map"><div id="map"></div></section>`,
})
class MapComponent {

    marker: any;
    compRef: ComponentRef<PopupComponent>;

    constructor(
        private mapService: MapService,
        private injector: Injector,
        private appRef: ApplicationRef,
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.mapService.init('map');
        this.mapService.component = PopupComponent;
        this.mapService.appRef = this.appRef;
        this.mapService.compRef = this.compRef;
        this.mapService.injector = this.injector;
        this.mapService.resolver = this.resolver;
        this.marker = this.mapService.addMarker();
    }
}

// ###########################################
// Main module
// ###########################################
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [
        MapService
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MapComponent,
        PopupComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        PopupComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. Using Angular2/4 with MapboxGL. Angular needs a f***ing compile function

Comment: Why not create a separate function for loading the component; which returns the HTMLElement directly into the marker.bindPopup function? I'm a little confused why you're setting bindPopup to null and handling inside of .on('click'). Couldn't you just do something like this: 

m.bindPopup(this.loadDynamicComponent());

Comment: I agree with @DouglasTober, not setting the bindPopup to null results in a more stable function(I had some strange results when setting it first to null). But other than that thanks for the answer! It really saved me!

Comment: hope you guys are still around. I was using this solution to generate a popup. It works "okay" for a single popup. However what if I wanted to do multiple popups. Also could someone provide code as to what it would look like if the code was not in a service but int he component itself? Or does it NEED to be in a service?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as well but with multiple popups as well @JamesMak .. Does anyone know how to get this working if you are constantly changing the component? I'm getting issues where previous popup data appears even though I click on a different point that has different metadata

Answer (score 3):

1. You will need to create a component for the popup content in case you don't have it already. Lets assume it is called `MycustomPopupComponent`.
2. Add your component to the `app.module.ts` in the entry components array. This is needed when creating components dynamically:

```
   entryComponents: [
      ...,
      MycustomPopupComponent
   ],
```

3. In your screen, add these two dependencies to the constructor:

```
constructor(
    ...
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector
) {
```

4. Now in that screen we can define a function that creates the component dynamically.

```
private createCustomPopup() { 
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MycustomPopupComponent);
    const component = factory.create(this.injector);

    //Set the component inputs manually 
    component.instance.someinput1 = "example";
    component.instance.someinput2 = "example";

    //Subscribe to the components outputs manually (if any)        
    component.instance.someoutput.subscribe(() => console.log("output handler fired"));

    //Manually invoke change detection, automatic wont work, but this is Ok if the component doesn't change
    component.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

    return component.location.nativeElement;
}
```

5. Finally, when creating the Leaflet popup, pass that function as parameter to bindPopup. That function also accepts a second parameter with options.:

```
const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude]).addTo(this.map);
marker.bindPopup(() => this.createCustomPopup()).openPopup();
```