# Angular 5 - ComponentFactoryResolver and properties

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular5

Hi I'm trying to render component view through ComponentFactoryResolver and put to the DOM, but properties are undefined on render, what to do in that case?

property in component:

```
@Input('productId') productId;
```

creating view and passing data to property:

```
const componentRef: any = this.componentFactoryResolver
  .resolveComponentFactory(component)
  .create(this.injector);
componentRef.instance.productId = data.productId;
```

and in template

```
<div>{{ productId }}</div>
```

productId is undefined

Comment: Probably because `data.productId` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

after you modify properties to invoke change detection.

See also https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef#changeDetectorRef

Comment: @peter 73 See also the 5 paragraph from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922224/angular2-component-into-dynamicaly-created-element/40926110#40926110